# Phantom wallet not enough sol

Tags: phantom

Edit: this has now been resolved itself, seems like phantom had an issues with devnet infrastructure. The next bug is [Unable to Simulate transaction warning on Phantom Wallet (browser, devnet)](https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/2287/unable-to-simulate-transaction-warning-on-phantom-wallet-browser-devnet/2350#comment2448_2350)
I am trying to do the deposit to another wallet, but i get following error:
[image]

I have a lot of sol on devnet, so not sure why is this appearing.

Comment: Can you screenshot the balances Phantom is showing in Devnet?

Comment: Are you transacting on devnet though? Devnet SOL has no use on mainnet.

Comment: Did you setup `Phantom` to use `devnet`? It defaults to `mainnet-beta`.

Comment: It could be phantom bugging out. You can try sending from CLI:
https://docs.solana.com/cli/transfer-tokens

Comment: "but i have to do it with wallet adapter in code" How did you set up the wallet adapter in the frontend code? Could it be that the connection in the frontend is connected to mainnet-beta instead of devnet?

Answer (score 2):

If you're sure you're on devnet can still be buggy with phantom